# how to get userID from db using spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new in Java Spring. I am creating a project using Spring Boot and I need to get userID of the current user. As far as I know, we can get current logged-in user by using Security Context Holder and here is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/posts/create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addPost(String username, Model model){
        Authentication auth= SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String name=auth.getName();
        UserDetails userDetial= (UserDetails) auth.getDetails();

        Users user= uRepo.findByUsername(userDetial.getUsername());
        Long id= user.getId();

        model.addAttribute("add", new Post());
        model.addAttribute("userId", id);
        model.addAttribute("authorName", name);
        return "posts/create";

    }
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code as I got error: "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails".

Is there anyone can explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message seems clear, you can't do this :

```
UserDetails userDetial= (UserDetails) auth.getDetails();
```

But you can do this :

```
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)auth.getPrincipal();
```

Or for short you can also inject directly `java.security.Principal` interface as follow

```
public String addPost(String username, Model model, Principal principal){
  String userUsername = principal.getName(); //gives you the username of the connected user
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Now I got another problem in my project. I would be grateful if you can answer. I got 2 tables Users and Post which author would be username in Users table. I don't know when I use the above way to get user Id, the user is now able to create only 1 post then the error: "java.lang.StackOverflowError: null" occur. Then I remove that way, I mean I input the user Id manually, the system works perfectly. I need the userId to connect 2 tables by the way

Comment: Create an other post for this and add the link here as a comment so I'll answer